# Cakephp collection how can I get array index?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

This is my collection data

```
[
   0 => object(App\Model\Entity\SummaryCoin) id:0 { 'user_id' => (int) 2
'total_sum_coin' => (float) 3 },
   1 => object(App\Model\Entity\SummaryCoin) id:1 { 'user_id' => (int) 1
'total_sum_coin' => (float) 33 },
]
```

How can I get the index where `user_id = 1`

Using first match I am able to get user 1 new collection

```
$sumOfUserCoins = $collection->firstMatch([
    'user_id' => 1
]);
```

How I will get the array index `1` that user have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific method for that, you'll have to be a little creative to obtain that information, for example match all instead so that you get a collection back, take everything away expect for the first entry, and convert it to an array that keeps the keys, from which you can then get that information:

```php
$userCoins = $collection
    ->match(['user_id' => 1])
    ->take(1)
    ->toArray();

$index = key($userCoins);
$coin = current($userCoins);
```